# Django - Serving MEDIA/uploaded files in production

Tags: python, django, apache, web

I currently have this in my project urls.py, the last line is what's important.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've been told and I've read that this is not suitable for a production environment. Why is this the case?

Comment: To further clarify, Django documentation states that this is not suitable for production use!  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django is built to be an "application server", not a "web server".

In other words, serving static files from Django will have worse performance than using Apache or Nginx. These static content servers are (1) written in C and (2) optimized for performance.

In contrast, Django is (1) written in pure Python and (2) optimized for developing an application.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

---

That may be totally fine. I have used Django to serve static content in production, when I knew the load would not be high and I wasn't serving large files. It depends on what kind of environment "production" actually is.

---

FYI, A [common](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) production setup would be to use Nignx, Django, Gunicorn, and Supervisor. Nginx servers the static content from disk and reverse proxies the rest of it to Gunicorn, which runs multiple Django instances. Supervisor monitors Gunicorn and makes sure it stays running. It all depends on what level of web application you need.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to serve static files from the django server itself. The recommended way is to serve them in a separate server. check [static files deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/), there you will find all you need.

Comment: I'm using webfaction and apache is serving my STATIC files but I am unsure how my MEDIA is being served. The media folder is currently inside my project folder while my `static_files` is outside it being served by apache. Should I place my media folder in static_files and make the proper connections? I'm mostly curious if I still need `+static(...) in my urls. YES/NO answer will suffice if you have the time :)

Comment: Hey, I'm also using webfaction. I have media folder also in a separate webfaction app (I guess you have one for static.). So, in the end, I have 3 different apps for each website, one for serving static, another for media and the other for Django itself. You don't need to specify the static line in urls.py. You just need to set the proper {MEDIA,STATIC }_ROOT and {MEDIA,STATIC}_URL (together with STATICFILES_DIRS if needed) to point them to the correct destination folder and configured urls (the ones you specified when assigning the apps to your website).

Comment: Btw, don't place media folder inside static_files, they are different things so keep the separated for better maintenance and structure of your project.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! Are you using Apache as well? I'm thinking of installing NGINX instead upon receiving a bunch of recommendations.

Comment: I'm using apache because it is the server it comes by default and because my servers don't have much load =). But yes, for static files it is recommended to use nginx because it has much better performance, for dynamic content both perform more or less. Long ago I read an article showing response times and all this stuff but can't find it... =/

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Paul Draper's answer:

When using Nginx, make sure to list the following configuration:

```
location /media/ {
        root path/to/your/media;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the tutorial for the [google section of the django-storages package](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) and it solves the issue serving the files (either static or media or both) from Google Storage, which avoids the trouble of additional configuration on Nginx or the like